# error evaluating function `lighten`: a.toHSL is not a function

Tags: css, less

Sorry for novice question. I am taking the first baby steps to learn Less and Sass. Here is my less syle in the file `style.less`:

```
@basecolor:#53353;

header {
    font-family: cursive,sans-serif;
    background-color: lighten(@basecolor, 50%);
    border: 5px solid darken(@basecolor, 50%);
    color:@basecolor;
    padding:  40px;
}
```

When i load the page, i face with the error:

```
RuntimeError: error evaluating function `lighten`: a.toHSL is not a function
```

I have looked at [this](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-darken), and it seems that the code is fine.
So what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your basecolor hex code only has 5 characters.  You need 3 or 6.

Comment: This could also be an issue with escaping your CSS code with ~''.  Lighten is probably already a less function so it needs to be escaped in your custom CSS. See my [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60713351/css-saturate-filter-issue/73759015#73759015).