# CSS Saturate filter Issue

Tags: css, filter, webkit

I am trying to use CSS saturate the filter and it has worked for me fine.

```
-webkit-backdrop-filter: saturate(110%) blur(10px);
backdrop-filter: saturate(110%) blur(10px);
```

Now I have to use it within Squarespace as custom CSS.  For saturate filter, it is giving me this error:

```
error evaluating function `saturate`: e.toHSL is not a function. (In 'e.toHSL()', 'e.toHSL' is undefined)
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Could this be a Squarespace preprocessing feature for CSS, like Sass? (I've never used Squarespace so I am not sure) Could you try with just the `blur`?

Comment: Works fine with just blur.

Comment: And with `saturate` alone, just to test it? I recommend you use only `blur` for now and file a ticket with Squarespace. Looks like you're doing everything right.

Comment: Saturate alone does not work.

Comment: Could also give `saturate(1.1)` a try. Looks unlikely to work given that error though.

Comment: For those looking to decrease the saturation you can use grayscale(1).

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with LESS CSS's compiler. You need to escape the text inside your `filter` with `~''` like this:

```
-webkit-backdrop-filter: ~'saturate(110%) blur(10px)';
backdrop-filter: ~'saturate(110%) blur(10px)';
```

I'm guessing it's because `saturate` is [already a function in LESS](https://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-saturate). This solution comes from [Squarespace's forums](https://forum.squarespace.com/topic/158556-css-saturate-filter-issue/).